# Gradient of the point with x coordinate

Tags: geometry

I am not even sure where to begin on solving this question

f(x) = $ax^2$ + bx + c, where a = -32, b = 9 and c = 14.  What is the gradient of the point, with x coordinate 11, on the graph of y = f(x)?

Comment: Do you know about differentiation?

Comment: @J.G. Yes I know a little about differentiation,This is more of a fixed point topic

Comment: Then differentiate $f$, the gradient will be $f'(11)$ (given any differentiable function $f$, the gradient at $x=a$ is defined as $f'(a)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya actually the answer was something like this according to the given formula

> In general, if f(x)= $ax^2$ + bx + c then the gradient at any point on
>   the graph of y=f(x) is given by f prime (x) = 2ax + b

so in the above sums case it will be 2(-32)(11)+9 = -695

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  plug the given $a,b,c$ into your function, differentiate with respect to $x$, and set $x=11$

Comment: Would my answer be correct?

Comment: @JackyBoi:  Yes it would.  Doing the differentiation symbolically saved you some computation, usually a good thing.